# How do always assign values to the last 2 row of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

hi there i have this code

```
r = input('key in row: ');
c = input('key in column: ');

board = zeros(r,c);

for i = 1:r
for j = 1:c
     board(i,j) = 1

     if i > 2

         board(i,j) = 0




     end

end
end
```

i would like to always assign the last 2 rows of the matrix to value '2' no matter what the user input for 'r' and 'c'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply after loop do following :

```
>> board(end-1:end,:)=2
```

Comment: fore a betteer answer do board(end-1:end,:)=2; ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri yep, I randomly used 5,5 to get the output, anyways, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not avoid the loops and just do

```
board = [ones(2,c);zeros(r-4,c);2*ones(2,c)];
```

This works for r>3. For smaller r it is not clear what the desired behavior is from the question, but for these cases, a similar approach is obvious.